# find the longest word and the largest number in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

So im learning python right now and i really need your help.
For example you do have random text file with words and numbers inside.
You need to find the longest word and maximum number in this file.
I managed to do the first half, i found the longest word:

```
def longest_word(word):
    with open(word, 'r') as infile:
        words = infile.read().split()
    max_len = len(max(words, key=len))
    return [word for word in words if len(word) == max_len]
print (("the longest word is :"), longest_word ('text.txt'))
```

can you help me with the second part? how to find maximum number in a file?

Comment: I recommend using regex to separate words from numbers, then finding the max for both.

Comment: Are these numbers: non-negative integers, integers or floats?

Comment: they're integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement error handling and try to parse the str as int: "2" --> 2

```py
def longest_integer(word):
    max_int = 0
    with open(word, 'r') as infile:
        words = infile.read().split()
    for word in words:
        try:
            int_val = int(word)
            if int_val > max_int:
                max_int = int_val
        except:
            pass
    return max_int
print (("the longest integer is :"), longest_integer ('text.txt'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! You can check each word to see if it's actually an integer, and then check if that value is greater than the previous max. **This assumes the goal is to find the largest integer**

```
for word in words:
    try:
        if int(word) > MAX_INT:
            MAX_INT = word
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: btw I'm fairly sure that each time through the loop that `word` will only ever be `str`.

Comment: @quamrana int('Hello 5 World'.split()[1]) gives 5, why do you think the above would only be str?

Comment: @Gocht That would also work. "Better to ask forgiveness than permission"

Comment: I think @quamrana refers to this case `isinstance('5', int)` (using your example)

Comment: Good catch. Edited to utilize try/except

Answer (score 0):

As numbers are integers you might get them using `str`'s method `isdigit`, consider following example:

```
words = ['abc', '123', 'xyz', '1', '999']
numbers = [i for i in words if i.isdigit()]
print(numbers)  # ['123', '1', '999']
```

then you might provide `max` with `int` as `key` following way:

```
print(max(numbers, key=int))  # 999
```

remember to NOT compare `strs` representing numbers as it might give surprising results, for example:

```
print(max(['9000','999']))  # 999
```

note that `ValueError` will occur if original list (`words`) do not contain any number.

Edit: I forget to note that above works solely for non-negative integers, to allow also negative one, you might write function for checking that as follow:

```
def represent_int(x):
    if not x:  # empty str
        return False
    if x[0] == '-':  # leading - that is negative integer
        return x[1:].isdigit()
    return x.isdigit()
```

and use it as follows:

```
numbers = [i for i in words if represent_int(i)]
```

note that I assume `represent_int` will be feeded solely with `str`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(word, 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    nums = [int(num) for num in re.findall('\d+', data)
    max_num = max(nums)
```